# Creating a table with cout, copied code formats differently

Tags: c++, printing, setw

I've spent like 3 hours creating with the ASCII characters a table, and at  the end i've correctly done one...But the problem is really weird...if i copy the table code and paste it again in the same program it formats differently! Why is it doing like this?

I've really spent a lot doing this and it's literally driving me insane! It's the exact same code...Please help needed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB3MO.png

The code is the following

```
  #include <iostream>   // Cout e cin
  #include <cstdlib>   // System Pause
  #include <iomanip>

  using namespace std;

  int main ()
  {

    cout<<char(218)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(12)<<char(194)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(194)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(194)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(191)<<endl;

    cout<<char(179)<<left<<setfill(' ')<<setw(11)<<"Algoritmo"<<char(179)<<left<<setfill(' ')<<setw(19)<<"Numero confronti"<<char(179)<<left<<setfill(' ')<<setw(19)<<"Numero copie"<<char(179)<<left<<setfill(' ')<<setw(19)<<"Tempo di esecuzione"<<char(179)<<endl;
    cout<<char(195)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(11)<<char(196)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(197)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(197)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(197)<<char(180)<<endl;
    cout<<char(192)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(11)<<char(196)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(193)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(193)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(193)<<char(217);

    cout<<endl;

    cout<<char(218)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(12)<<char(194)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(194)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(194)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(191)<<endl;

    cout<<char(179)<<left<<setfill(' ')<<setw(11)<<"Algoritmo"<<char(179)<<left<<setfill(' ')<<setw(19)<<"Numero confronti"<<char(179)<<left<<setfill(' ')<<setw(19)<<"Numero copie"<<char(179)<<left<<setfill(' ')<<setw(19)<<"Tempo di esecuzione"<<char(179)<<endl;
    cout<<char(195)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(11)<<char(196)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(197)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(197)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(197)<<char(180)<<endl;
    cout<<char(192)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(11)<<char(196)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(193)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20)<<char(193)<<setfill(char(196))<<setw(20) <<char(193)<<char(217);



    cout<<endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: There's a missing ) in the last line...

Comment: Thank you for letting me know but it was just while copying it here to  the thread, i had it in my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the justification of your text. The first time you print the table, you use `left` to set the justification. You should use `cout << right` before printing the second table.

Each stream has a set of format flags. At the start of the program, standard streams (for example, `cout`) have their `adjustfield` set to `right`. That is why the first time you print your table, everything works: the first line of your table code correctly assumes right-justified text. Once you set the justification to `left` on the second line, it remains that way until you change it. So you can actually remove the other `left`s on the second line of your table code, because the first one is enough.

For the second table code to work correctly, you need to revert back to right justification. So right after the empty line between the two tables, you should insert `cout << right;`.

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with this...i've tried replacing the other lefts' with rights' and it doesn't work either...

Comment: Can you please  help me understanding why that right is needed?

Comment: I've added some more explanations in my answer. Hope that helps.